# Rewrite objec WP POST in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Why I can not rewrite object like as:

```
$ps =  get_post($post->id_content_replacement);
$post = $ps;
```

Where `$ps` is object Post too from action:

```
add_action('the_post', array($this, 'post_callback'));
```

So, I tried to modify object `the_post` by `get_post()`